# Laravel 8 string between function doesn't work properly

Tags: laravel

When using the `Str::between` function from Laravel 8, it jumps over the first occurrence of the 'TO' variable. Is there something wrong I'm doing, or is it broken?

```
<span class="website-title">Name</span> All Rights Reserved.</p>';

$slice = Str::between($string, '<span class="current-year">', '</span>');
```

Returns '2022 Name' when it should only return '2022.'

Answer (score 0):

I think it finds the last occurrence of the last parameter in the between method. To solve this, you could do something like

```php
$slice = Str::between($string, 
          '<span class="current-year">', 
          '</span> <span class="website-title">');
```